# Google Mail Fetcher not fetching emails

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email

I have just setup a Google Apps account as I want to use Gmail and use my website's domain. I want to fetch all the emails from my current webmail account (e.g me@someone.com) into the Gmail account I have setup and at the moment it will not fetch them. When I use the “Add a mail account you own” function it displays a `You cannot create a mail account for ...` error message. And this maybe due to the webmail account name being identical to the Gmail account name. Is there a work around for this? Because I believe you should be able to fetch emails from identical account names.

Answer (score 2):

when adding account, enter any (random) email address, even if from your existing domain. It doesn't really matter, except for some "sanity" checks.

Then input correct login, password and POP3 server address. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

The webmail address and your gmail address is same. Hence you cannot create it. Even when I tried to do the same thing half year ago, I faced same problem.

If you want to migrate all your old mails, then you can go for Windows Live mail or Thunderbird (not sure). First setup both accounts in IMAP mode and then just move your mails from old account to new one.